# Slope from a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was wondering if I have a graph with no points specified and they only say find the slope how do I do it like what am I supposed to do and how can I find out the points

Comment: You should change the tags on this question; this isn't related to algebraic graph theory.

Comment: Some more context is necessary for anyone to help you. Are you given an equation that describes the graph? Are you just given a picture of the graph?

Answer (score 2):

The graph you showed for problem 3 depicts a line that passes through the points $(-1, 3)$ and $(2, 4)$.  You can use those two points to find the slope using the formula

$$m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$

by defining $(x_1, y_1)$ to be $(-1, 3)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ to be $(2, 4)$.

Comment: How did u get the points

Comment: How did u get the points

Comment: I noticed that the line passes through the intersection of two grid lines one unit to the left and three units above the origin, yielding the point $(-1, 3)$.  The line also passes through the intersection of two grid lines two units to the right and four units above the origin, yielding the point $(2, 4)$.

Comment: I read I can choose any 2 points in a line and apply slope formula and my answer will be correct is it true ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank u, one last question can a slope be like 2.66?

Comment: Yes.  In this case, you should get $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: for ex this graph]

Like this graph for ex no points nothing just it says find the slope

Comment: This should be added to your question itself

Answer (score 0):

If you're given just one line then You've to draw another line parallel to x axis( in my image the x axis itself ) and then find angle the line between them, In my case it's $\alpha=53.13^0$ , Now slope is
$$m=\tan\alpha=\frac{4}{3}$$

[image]